# Is an NP-complete problem also an NP-hard?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard

We can say that an NP-complete problem is one which is in NP and in NP-hard, but can we argue exclusively that a problem is NP-hard solely due to the fact that it is NP-complete.

Example: I reduce an NP-complete problem `a` to a problem `b`. Therefore, problem `b` is now proven to be NP-complete. Can I actually say that it is also NP-hard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of NP completeness is:

> A problem Q is NP-complete if and only if Q is in NP and Q is NP-hard.

Therefore, yes, we can most definitely say that any NP-complete problem is NP-hard, *by definition.*

Note that you have a slight misstatement in your question:

> Example: I reduce an NP-complete problem `a` to a problem `b`. Therefore, problem `b` is now proven to be NP-complete.

The above conclusion only holds if you've shown `b` to be in NP. If `b` is "harder" than NP, then it is *not* NP-complete. Note, however, that the reduction is enough to prove that `b` is NP-hard.

Comment: But then for sure it is going to be NP-hard, since the reduction means that b is at least as hard as a, right?